# remove a dictionary from a dictionary based on a conditoon

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to remove a dictionary from a nested dictionary based on  a condition.

dict :

```
{1: {'A': [1, 2, 3, 0], 'B': ['ss', 'dd', 'ff', 'aa']},
 2: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ee', 'ff', 'bb', 'gg']},
 3: {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']},
 4: {'A': [ 1, 0], 'B': [ 'll', 'jj']}}
```

I want to remove if  'A' == 0, then if B isnt starting with a, then I want to delete that particular dictionary.

Expected:

```
{1: {'A': [1, 2, 3, 0], 'B': ['ss', 'dd', 'ff', 'aa']},
 
 2: {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']},
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
s=pd.DataFrame(d)

new_d = s.loc[:,s.loc['B'].str[0].str[0]=='a'].to_dict()
Out[99]: 
{1: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff']},
 3: {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume the keys change on the new dictionary is on purpose, so here is a simple solution with no extra libraries(`nested` is your dictionary)

```
temp = [x for x in nested.values() if 0 in x['A'] and any([i[0] == 'a' for i in x['B']])]
new_dict = dict(enumerate(temp, 1))
```

if you want you can make it a one liner, or you can split the condition to be a function
like this

```
def check(x):
    if 0 in x['A']:
        return any([i[0] == 'a' for i in x['B']])
    return True

temp = [x for x in nested.values() if check(x)]
```

Now if you prefer using `filter()` the above 2 variations become:

```
temp = filter(lambda x: 0 in x['A'] and any(i[0] == 'a' for i in x['B']), nested.values())
```

and if you decide to declare `check()` like above you can do it in this elegant way(notice i use new_dict here, instead of temp since it doen's make sence to split it when it so compact)

```
new_dict = dict(enumerate(filter(check, nested.values()),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarity.
Assuming you intend to delete

```
{
 1: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff']},
 2: {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']},
}
```

from

```
{1: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff']},
 2: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ee', 'ff', 'bb', 'gg']},
 3: {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']},
 4: {'A': [0, 1], 'B': ['jj', 'll']}}
```

You can try this:

```
import re

r = re.compile("a.*")
input_dictionary = {
    1: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff']},
    2: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ee', 'ff', 'bb', 'gg']},
    3: {'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': ['ar', 'hh', 'ww']},
    4: {'A': [0, 1], 'B': ['jj', 'll']}}

key_list = list(input_dictionary.keys())

for key in key_list:    
    value = input_dictionary[key]
    
    if(any(r.match(b_element) for b_element in value['B']) and 0 in value['A']):
        
        del input_dictionary[key]
        print("Deleting key: ", key)
```